# Check if multiple entries exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

In SQL Server 2022 (v15), I have this table:

```
Table file
-------------
Id    name        Md5
1     abc.txt     xxxxx1
2     bbb.doc     xxxxx2
3     ccc.bin     xxxxx3
```

If the client passes some md5s to query if these files in the database, I can make a query like,

```
SELECT Md5 
FROM file 
WHERE md5 IN ('xxx1', 'xxx2', ...)
```

This query returns a dataset with the existing file Md5s. The client needs to write some extra code to know whether xxx1 exists, whether xxx2 exists ...

Can I give the result for each file in the query? Like,

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 'xxx1' IN ('xxx1', 'xxx2', ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS 'xxx1',
    CASE WHEN 'xxx2' IN ('xxx1', 'xxx2', ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS 'xxx2',
    ...
FROM
    ....
WHERE 
    Md5 IN ('xxx1', 'xxx2', ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to start with a table of the MD5 hashes to check, and left-join the `file` table.

You can use a `VALUES` constructor

```sql
SELECT
  v.Md5,
  f.Id   -- this column is NULL if not matched
FROM (VALUES
    (0xxxx1),
    (0xxxx2),
    (0xxxx8)
) v(md5)
LEFT JOIN file f ON f.md5 = v.md5;
```

Or, depending on how you pass the data in, you can use a table variable, temp table or Table-Valued Parameter.

```sql
DECLARE @values TABLE (md5 binary(32) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @values (md5)
VALUES
    (0xxxx1),
    (0xxxx2),
    (0xxxx8);

SELECT
  v.Md5,
  f.Id   -- this column is NULL if not matched
FROM @values v
LEFT JOIN file f ON f.md5 = v.md5;
```

The results would be something like this

| Md5 | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 0xxxx1 | 1 |
| 0xxxx2 | 2 |
| 0xxxx8 | *NULL* |

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple `PIVOT`

**Note:**  The `WHERE` is optional, but may be more performant

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  (Select Md5
         From  YourTable
         Where md5 in ('xxxxx1', 'xxxxx2')  -- << Optional
       ) src
 Pivot ( count(Md5) for Md5 in ([xxxxx1], [xxxxx2]) ) Pvt
```

**Results**

```
xxxxx1  xxxxx2
1       1
```